# Python Numerical Sorting of Strings

Tags: python, sorting

How do I make Python sorting behave like `sort -n` from GNU coreutils?

This is my `images.txt`:

```
Vol. 1/Vol. 1 - Special 1/002.png
Vol. 1/Chapter 2 example text/002.png
Vol. 1/Vol. 1 Extra/002.png
Vol. 1/Chapter 2 example text/001.png
Vol. 1/Vol. 1 Extra/001.png
Vol. 1/Chapter 1 example text/002.png
Vol. 1/Vol. 1 - Special 1/001.png
Vol. 1/Chapter 1 example text/001.png
```

When I run this Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat images.txt | sort -n
```

I get the following output:

```
Vol. 1/Chapter 1 example text/001.png
Vol. 1/Chapter 1 example text/002.png
Vol. 1/Chapter 2 example text/001.png
Vol. 1/Chapter 2 example text/002.png
Vol. 1/Vol. 1 Extra/001.png
Vol. 1/Vol. 1 Extra/002.png
Vol. 1/Vol. 1 - Special 1/001.png
Vol. 1/Vol. 1 - Special 1/002.png
```

But when I run this Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

images = []

with open("images.txt") as images_file:
    for image in images_file:
        images.append(image)

images = sorted(images)

for image in images:
    print(image, end="")
```

I get the following output, which is not what I need:

```
Vol. 1/Chapter 1 example text/001.png
Vol. 1/Chapter 1 example text/002.png
Vol. 1/Chapter 2 example text/001.png
Vol. 1/Chapter 2 example text/002.png
Vol. 1/Vol. 1 - Special 1/001.png
Vol. 1/Vol. 1 - Special 1/002.png
Vol. 1/Vol. 1 Extra/001.png
Vol. 1/Vol. 1 Extra/002.png
```

How do I achieve the same result with Python that I achieve with Bash and `sort -n`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Comment: I'm not sure there's an in-built method, seems like `-` is treated differently. Maybe `sorted(L, key=lambda x: x.replace(' - ', ' '))` ?

Comment: I am missing the "numerical" part of your question. The numbers are sorted equally in both examples.

Comment: @jpp Thank you, that works. Can you please submit your solution as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm no [gnu](/questions/tagged/gnu) expert, it seems `'-'` is ordered differently versus Python. A quick fix for this particular issue is to replace `' - '` with `' '` when sorting:

```
L = sorted(L, key=lambda x: x.replace(' - ', ' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider a lambda which replaces all non alpha numeric characters

```
images = sorted(images, key=lambda x: re.sub('[^A-Za-z\d]+', '', x))
```